# Android Widget for x10 mini phones

Tags: android, widget

I have developed an application with a widget (size 2x2), in normal screens its just fine!

I tried it on a x10 mini and the widget goes very tiny and the layout is horrible, what can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try a separate res/layout-small/mywidget.xml ?